# mongoose - how to get subdocument to comply with a schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I have the following schemas:

```
var Item_Detail = new Schema(
    {
        content: {
            index: true,
            type: Array
        },
        is_private: {
            default: false,
            index: true,
            type: Boolean
        },
        order: {
            index: true,
            required: true,
            type: Number
        },
        table: {
            default: {},
            type: Object
        },
        title: {
            required: true,
            index: true,
            type: String,
        },
        type: {
            default: "text",
            enum: ["text", "table"],
            index: true,
            type: String
        },
    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
)

const Item = new Schema(
    {
        details: {
            default: [],
            index: true,
            type: [Item_Detail],
        },
        display_name: {
            default: "",
            index: true,
            type: String,
        },
        image: {
            default: "http://via.placeholder.com/700x500/ffffff/000000/?text=No%20Image&",
            type: String
        },
        is_private: {
            default: false,
            index: true,
            type: Boolean
        },
        tags: {
            index: true,
            type: [Tag]
        }
    },
    {
        strict: false
    }
)
```

Now, `Item_Detail` is to be a subdocument of `Item`, but I'm not quite sure how I should enforce the `default`s and `type` restriction. I also don't want `Item_Detail` to be a collection in its own right, so using `create` or `save` probably doesn't fit.

Comment: So you want to have in `Item Schema` details a reference to `type` with the `_id` of the item detail and what in the `defaults` array?

Comment: @Akrion the default can just be an empty array

Comment: What about the `type` what do you want to have in there? Cross-reference id for the Item Schema? If so then you just need to add a `ref`

Comment: @Akrion `type` is just a string. `Item_Details` is a subdocument of `Item`, it shouldn't exist independently i.e. as a collection.

Comment: only put `_id` of **Item** in **Item_Detail**... and use `$lookup` aggregation to get them

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Item_Detail is not a collection in and of itself, it exists inside `Item`

Comment: Yes that's why I am suggesting you to make a seperate collection... A lot of benefits of that

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [embedded documents](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) for this so in your item schema you can **embed** an item_detail:

```
const Item = new Schema({
    ...
    item_detail: item_detail
})
```

Then on the server when you want to add an item_detail you can do the following

```
myItem = new Item({//enter item data here})
//assign item detail here
myItem.item_detail = item_detail ;
```

then proceed to save it

```
myItem.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Enforcing the type is easy the default value is the tricky one but `mongoose` allows you to [specify a function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-default) instead of boolean for `default` (just like it allows you the [same for required](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required)).

So you could do something like this (I shortened the schemas for bravity):

```
const itemDetails = new Schema({
  info: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const item = new Schema({
  details: {
    default: function() {
      return [new ItemDetails({ info: 'N/A' })]
    },
    type: [itemDetails],
  }
})
```

This would allow you to do something like this:

```
var itm = new Item();
```

And the saved result would be:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5b72795d4aa17339b0815b8b"),
  "details": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b72795d4aa17339b0815b8c"),
    "info": "N/A"
  }]
}
```

So this gives you two things:

1. You cannot put any type in `details` other than `itemDetails` since you enforced the type with `itemDetails`.
2. You initialize your `ItemDetails` object with defaults you want in your `default` custom function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see why I couldn't just move the `default` into itemDetails `info`? My problem is that `table` isn't being initialised.

Comment: Ok but you did not mention anything about `table` in your question. I am just giving an example where you can use the `default` as a function to initialize `anything` you want ... including table.

Comment: Also please note that Mongoose does not have type `Object` but `Mixed` so you can make table `Mixed` and then use `default` to initialize it any way you want.